# systemctl service not starting after system restart

Tags: linux, restart, systemd, ubuntu-15.10

I have this service which I want to be able to start as a service on system restart. I am using Ubuntu 15.10. The service configuration file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Service client 
After=syslog.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/service_clientd start"
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "/usr/local/bin/service_clientd stop"
Type=simple

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service starts perfectly with systemctl command, but does not start automatically after system restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
systemctl enable servicename.service
```

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Using_units

Comment: Exactly what i needed! Thanks a lot! =D

Comment: Doing this I get: cloudera-scm-server.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig cloudera-scm-server on